# How to run JAGS as fast as possible on Mac?

Tags: r, jags

I am running lots of simulations in JAGS 3.1.0 , which I have compiled from source. I am using a mid-2009 Macbook Pro 13 2.53GHz.
Is there any step by step tutorial (from scratch) to compile ATLAS or GotoBLAS for JAGS and R (where I use the rjags package)? There are information on ATLAS, GotoBLAS, JAGS, and R compilation, but for one reason or another I was not successful in getting them to work together. And lastly, does it even help the speed of simulations with the machine that I am using?

Note: I am not looking for parallel processing since I am running two separate simulations simultaneously which use the 2 cores of CPU.

Comment: if you don't get an answer here, try the recently (09/2010) opened [JAGS forum on sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mcmc-jags/forums/forum/610037). The developer, Martyn Plummer, is very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Accelerated BLAS like Goto or Atlas are very useful for speeding up linear algebra operation.

That said, *common* applications programs in R or Jags or ... are typically not bound but the linear algebra performance. The net effect on your particular problem may well be a single digit gain in performance: not shabby, but not earth-shattering either.

Most likely, you would be *much* better off getting a way to run more chains in parallel: more cores, more machines, ...

Comment: Hi, is there anything like running Jags code on GPU?

Comment: In general you cannot just copy code over, so no.  You'd need to redo it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [macports project](http://www.macports.org/)? I use a GUI called Porticus to make it more convenient, and macports does have a port of ATLAS in it.

Comment: yes, but how do you link macports' ATLAS to JAGS and R?

Comment: I'd have to look at it to see if it worked for me or not. It seems like the build script found ATLAS, but perhaps it did not or perhaps I tweaked something before the make.